# Copulas and marginals thereof

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Hello everyone,

I recently became aware of the existence of the copula concept.
So, I have been reading a few things about copulas lately, but
I cannot seem to find information on the following question:

- Let's say that I have marginals for the random variables a,b,c,d.
- Is it possible to learn a copula from the 4 marginals p(a),p(b),p(c),p(d)
  that allows me to derive then any marginal I might be interested in?

E.g. once I have obtained the copula c(a,b,c,d), can I calculate the marginal for (a,d)?

Thank you in advance!
N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes, it's Sklar's theorem.

The copula is merely a form of normalization that makes all your marginals U(0,1). Given a copula and the marginals, you can reconstruct the original distribution, and a fortiori get any marginal you're interested in.

Comment: Dear Arthur,

your prompt answer is much appreciated.
Please bear with me, I must sit myself down and have a serious think:)
as I seem to have misunderstood some fundamentals...

Comment: @Arthur: I think you should seek clarification from the OP, first. There is no way to "learn" (I assume this means *estimate* or *infer*) a copula *from the marginal distributions*. You can *specify* a copula and based on that and the assumed marginals, recover the joint distribution of any subset of the random variables, but the only way you could try to infer a copula is if you had a sample (or other collection) of *random vectors*.

Comment: Thank you both, I suppose one needs sometimes a little push to get unstuck...

Comment: Ah yes, I focused on the last line and missed that bullet point! There are many different distribution that share the same marginals, so marginals aren't enough to recover the original distribution.